# Firebase find .info/connected of another user

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Any idea how to find the online status of all other users from firebase realtime database?

If I look for `.info/connected` of the current user, I will receive that user's status, But how will we find the same of another user?

Say I am Joe. Joe knows his status from 'info/connected'.
But Joe also want to the status of John.

How will Joe get info/connected of John?
Any way to make that happen?

Comment: Use John's app's `/.info/connected` to write another value that you can query to see if John is currently using your app.

Answer (score 0):

`.info/connected` is not meant to be used to detect online/offline state of other users.

Its main purpose is for the app to know if you are connected/disconnected from the firebase database.

From the documentation :

> /.info/connected is a boolean value which is not synchronized between Realtime Database clients because the value is dependent on the state of the client. In other words, if one client reads /.info/connected as false, this is no guarantee that a separate client will also read false.

The best way to check if other users are online would would be to just create a entry in your database everytime a user logs in and then depending on that value show if the user is online or offline.

The following tutorial might be helpful :

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XqOwBpadozA&t=1s